# Replace items of list except items that are member of another list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I want to replace all items in `li1` that are not members of `li2` with `x`.
`Except` does not seem to work well with `/.` as can be seen in third line of output.
Fourth line of output is correct but I used cumbersome code to produce it.

Do you have a more elegant solution?

```
li1=Transpose[{Range[10],Range[10,1,-1]}]
li2={{4,7},{9,2},{2,9},{5,6}}
li1 /. Except[Alternatives@@li2] -> x
({#,MemberQ[li2,#]}&/@li1)/.{{n_,False}->x,{n_,True}->n}
Clear[li1,li2]

(* {{1,10},{2,9},{3,8},{4,7},{5,6},{6,5},{7,4},{8,3},{9,2},{10,1}} *)
(* {{4,7},{9,2},{2,9},{5,6}} *)
(* x *)
(* {x,{2,9},x,{4,7},{5,6},x,x,x,{9,2},x} *)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
Map[If[MemberQ[li2, #], #, x] &, li1]
```

Answer (score 11):

The reason `Except` is not working for you is because the entire list `li1` also matches that pattern, so everything is simply replaced by `x`. To fix it, you need to make sure `Except` matches only what you want. The easiest is to simply use [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) with a level specification of 1:

```
Replace[li1, Except[Alternatives @@ li2] -> x, 1]
(* {x, {2, 9}, x, {4, 7}, {5, 6}, x, x, x, {9, 2}, x} *)
```

An alternative is to use the second argument of [`Except`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Except.html) to force it to only match pairs of things (note that this will fail when `li1` is itself two elements long):

```
li1 /. Except[Alternatives @@ li2, {_, _}] -> x
(* {x, {2, 9}, x, {4, 7}, {5, 6}, x, x, x, {9, 2}, x} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
(li1 /. Thread[
   Rule[Complement[Union[li1, li2], Intersection[li1, li2]], x]])
```

> `{x, {2, 9}, x, {4, 7}, {5, 6}, x, x, x, {9, 2}, x}`

Answer (score 4):

Using `Position` and `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[#, Position[#, Alternatives @@ Complement[#, li2]] -> x] &@li1

(*{x, {2, 9}, x, {4, 7}, {5, 6}, x, x, x, {9, 2}, x}*)
```

Or using `SubsetMap`:

```
pos = Position[#, Alternatives @@ Complement[#, li2]] &@li1

(*{{1}, {3}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {10}}*)

SubsetMap[Array[x &, Length@#] &, li1, #] &@pos

(*{x, {2, 9}, x, {4, 7}, {5, 6}, x, x, x, {9, 2}, x}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

A slot-free variant of E. Chan-López' second solution:

```
a = Transpose[{Range[10], Range[10, 1, -1]}];
b = {{4, 7}, {9, 2}, {2, 9}, {5, 6}};

With[{p = Position[a, Alternatives @@ b]},
 SubsetMap[
  Extract[a, p] &,
  Table[x, Length @ a],
  Flatten @ p]]
```

{x, {2, 9}, x, {4, 7}, {5, 6}, x, x, x, {9, 2}, x}

Answer (score 4):

```
li1/.Join[Thread[li2->li2],{{_,_}->x}]

(* {x,{2,9},x,{4,7},{5,6},x,x,x,{9,2},x} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Sow/Reap`:**

```
li1 = Transpose[{Range[10], Range[10, 1, -1]}]
li2 = {{4, 7}, {9, 2}, {2, 9}, {5, 6}}

Scan[If[MemberQ[li2, #], Sow@#, Sow@x] &, li1] // Reap // Last
```

---

**Using `Position`:**

```
Position[li2, #] & /@ li1 /. {{} :> x, {{a_}} :> li2[[a]]}
```

---

**Using `MapIndexed` and `Boole`:**

```
MapIndexed[
 If[# === 1, li1[[First@#2]], x] &, (Boole[MemberQ[li2, #]] & /@ li1 /. 
   0 -> x)]
```

---

*Result:*

{{x, {2, 9}, x, {4, 7}, {5, 6}, x, x, x, {9, 2}, x}}